# Nginx DDoS SSL Cert

Tags: proxy, ssl, https, nginx

Ok, So I have a Nginx reverse proxy that is blocking this incoming Layer 7 DDoS.

The problem is, my outgoing is massive the only assumption I have come to is that my server is sending the SSL Certificates to the ddoser?
I have it set to give error 444 when someone is blocked so it should in theory not send any data and I tested it on my browser by changing my user agent and it gave me a no data sent error so why is my Outgoing on my server so high?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question seems unanswerable in its current state. We can't really tell you why there is so much traffic. I also don't see what you mean by that you "have the server set to give error 444"; what gives that error, and what does that error mean, and at what point is it given? Really the only suggestion I have is to use a network sniffer such as Wireshark, and if you are having trouble interpreting the data then ask a different question about *that*.

Comment: If you read carefully, I have an nginx proxy I make it give error 444 which is the no data sent error to any malicious http requests. But for some reason SSL certificates are still being sent to these malicious requests making my outgoing on my server a lot and I would like it to not send the SSL certificates to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

error 444 is an http error.

If your nginx is reverse proxying an https site, then there's no http until the TLS layer has been set up.  So your server will be replying to the client helo packet with the server helo containing the certificate.

You'd need to block at the IP level to prevent this.

Comment: Well when I am not doing HTTPS the outgoing traffic is greatly decreased on my end so it definitely has to do something with HTTPS.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm saying - your question was why is your outgoing so high.  Your assumption that setting nginx to give a 444 error when someone is blocked does not prevent the TLS setup which is causing your traffic.  That's why I suggested blocking at the IP/TCP level